# Title styling in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I couldn't style the title to mimic OOB title style. Any suggestion would be very helpful

```
<template>
  <div class="slds-card slds-box">
    <div class="slds-box slds-theme_shade">
      <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:account" title="Final Report"></lightning-icon>

      <span class="slds-text-title titlestyle"><b>Final Report</b></span>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 300px">
      <lightning-datatable key-field="id" data={data} columns={columns}> </lightning-datatable>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
.titlestyle {
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[image: Title needs to bold to mimic OOB styling]

Based on Manju link, I can change the styling of title thank you so much. However , It is appearing in separate line.

```
<template>
  <div class="slds-card slds-box">
    <div class="slds-box slds-theme_shade">
      <span>
        <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:account"></lightning-icon>
      </span>
      <div class="slds-page-header__name-title">
        <h1>
          <span class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate" title="Final Report">Final Report</span>
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 300px">
      <lightning-datatable key-field="Id" data={data} columns={columns}> </lightning-datatable>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: SLDS site is the best place to look for OOTB styling and mimic them. It looks like you need a padding to the left of `Final Report`, you can get more complete code here: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/page-headers/#Inside-a-card

Comment: is it spacing where you are facing the issue I tried the same code in the playground and also in my org but I was able to get the necessary space between the icon and title, can you mention what is the difference you are seeing between your implementation and standard one

Comment: Both spacing and making it bolder and bigger

Comment: @manjit5190, Thanks for the link. I can able achieve the styling. However, the title is appearing in next line. Can you able let me know from above code what i need to add .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the code in this [documentation link](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/page-headers/#Inside-a-card) I was able to modify the code and I was able to use the below code and I was able to get it in the same line and in h1 font size, please try checking the below code:

```
 <template>
<div class="slds-page-header">
    <div class="slds-page-header__row">
    <div class="slds-page-header__col-title">
    <div class="slds-media">
    
    <div class="slds-media__figure">
    
    <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account" title="opportunity">
        <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:account" title="Final Report" size="medium"> </lightning-icon> 
    <span class="slds-assistive-text">opportunity</span>
    
    </span>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="slds-media__body">
    <div class="slds-page-header__name">
    <div class="slds-page-header__name-title">
    <h1>
    <span class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate" title="Final Report">Final Report</span>
    </h1>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>   </template>
```

Comment: thank you.. I added this with little tweet.